# Webpage Keeps Jumping Back to On-Page Anchor

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site locally that has a fixed navbar with links that direct to on-page anchors. Everything was going fine, but then I realized at one point that upon clicking the link the page jumps to the anchor and then continues to jump back to the anchor every few seconds. I haven't put in any new javascript in, and I'm really at a loss for what could be causing the issue. Any ideas about what could be responsible?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but could it be a cache issue? Clear the cache and see how it behaves.

Comment: can you share the snippet?